# Script trying to define a function from the wrong file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function

I want to call a function 'addArray' in a separate .js file called 'main.js'
When I run this code, I get an error saying the 'addArray' is not defined in checkout.js
I don't want it to look for the function in checkout.js, I want it to look for the function in main.js
I am using node.js

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <script src = "https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
    <script>
        paypal.Button.render(
        {
                onAuthorize: function(data, actions) 
                {
                    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() 
                    {
                        // Show a confirmation message to the buyer             
                        days = 30
                        localStorage.setItem("days", days);
                        inputDays = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('days'));
                        inputName = localStorage.getItem('name');
                        window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');
                        console.log(inputDays);
                        console.log(inputName);
                        addArray();
                    });
                }
            }, '#paypal-button');
```

I had to delete most of the intermediate non essential code for the purpose of submitting this question

Answer (score 0):

So... There are a few things I think you should check for.

1. If you are using commonJS, be sure that you are exporting the addArray function like so: `module.exports = {addArray}`; Then require it from your main.js file.
2. If you are using es6 syntax, you can export it like `export default addArray` or `export {addArray}`, then import it in your main.js file using the `import {addArray} from...` or `import addArray from ...` depending on the export style you used.

Comment: How do I know if I am using es6 syntax? Sorry, I am only new to java coding. Also, is the import in the script file or where do I put it?

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) is the error I get when I run the code